# 2.2.4 cloned, search not working

Tags: magento2.2, white-screen, blank

I've created a 2.2.4 magento website a few month ago. My client wanted to clone this website, in order to have 2 different databases but keep all the fonctionnalities.

So I've cloned this website, updated the catalog etc...

Everything works fine, except the catalog research. I'm having a blank page each time I do the search.

I saw nothing in the php, apache, mysql or magento log (system or debug)...

This is the source code that I have :

[image]

EDIT : after digging into my log, those error are thrown but not on the search page (so, I guess it's stopping before). This is similar to another issue, I tried removing some block in my Magento_Theme::default.xml file, but I still have the white screen...

[image]

Comment: if you don't see anything in log, it's time to start debugging, like when you hit enter to search, what route/controller handles the search for you.

Comment: where do I see that ? by the CLI ?

Comment: so you are not Magento developer then, this is a technical issue, you should have someone checked it for you

Comment: I'm alone to check thoses issues. I've never have any issues like that, don't know where to look at

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution ! I had to overwrite the initial controller that does the search. Indeed, after cloning my projet, some of the initial code from the controller made only white page. I never thought that the core could be so affected.  This is the code I'm talking about

```
  $this->_view->loadLayout();
  $this->_view->renderLayout();
```

And this is how I fixed it. i had to to replace it by a **page factory**. I have no idea why it stopped working, but page factory fixed it.

in vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\SearchResult\Index"/>
```

And the controller in vendor/module/Controller/SearchResult/Index.php

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Catalog session
     *
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $_catalogSession;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var QueryFactory
     */
    private $_queryFactory;

    /**
     * Catalog Layer Resolver
     *
     * @var Resolver
     */
    private $layerResolver;

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $pageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $catalogSession
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param QueryFactory $queryFactory
     * @param Resolver $layerResolver
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $catalogSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Display search result
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->layerResolver->create(Resolver::CATALOG_LAYER_SEARCH);

        /* @var $query \Magento\Search\Model\Query */
        $query = $this->_queryFactory->get();

        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $query->setStoreId($storeId);

        $queryText = $query->getQueryText();

        if ($queryText != '') {
            $catalogSearchHelper = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data::class);

            $getAdditionalRequestParameters = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            unset($getAdditionalRequestParameters[QueryFactory::QUERY_VAR_NAME]);

            if (empty($getAdditionalRequestParameters) &&
                $this->_objectManager->get(PopularSearchTerms::class)->isCacheable($queryText, $storeId)
            ) {
                $this->getCacheableResult($catalogSearchHelper, $query);
            } else {
                $this->getNotCacheableResult($catalogSearchHelper, $query);
            }
        } else {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        }
        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Return cacheable result
     *
     * @param \Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data $catalogSearchHelper
     * @param \Magento\Search\Model\Query $query
     * @return void
     */
    private function getCacheableResult($catalogSearchHelper, $query)
    {
        if (!$catalogSearchHelper->isMinQueryLength()) {
            $redirect = $query->getRedirect();
            if ($redirect && $this->_url->getCurrentUrl() !== $redirect) {
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect);
                return;
            }
        }

        $catalogSearchHelper->checkNotes();

        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Return not cacheable result
     *
     * @param \Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data $catalogSearchHelper
     * @param \Magento\Search\Model\Query $query
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function getNotCacheableResult($catalogSearchHelper, $query)
    {
        if ($catalogSearchHelper->isMinQueryLength()) {
            $query->setId(0)->setIsActive(1)->setIsProcessed(1);
        } else {
            $query->saveIncrementalPopularity();
            $redirect = $query->getRedirect();
            if ($redirect && $this->_url->getCurrentUrl() !== $redirect) {
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect);
                return;
            }
        }

        $catalogSearchHelper->checkNotes();

        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```